# Get a word from delimited a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on string of sentences and need to get specific sentence from the paragraph.

Example input
‘Tom is a cat. He loves playing outside. He also love eating.’

The separator is ‘.’, If I need the second sentence then:
The result should be ‘He loves playing outside’

This should be done via ms sql scalar function.

Comment: Why are you using unsupported softare?

Comment: I have to, this is the clients database and can’t be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the data types and the search location (I don't know how many spaces and such you may have) to meet your needs, but here are the basics:

```
create function dbo.udf_SecondSentence (@s varchar(200))
returns varchar(200)
begin
    declare @n1 int
    , @n2 int

    set @n1 = CHARINDEX('.', @s)
    set @n2 = CHARINDEX('.', @s, CHARINDEX('.', @s) + 1)

    return SUBSTRING(@s, @n1 + 2, @n2 - @n1 - 2)
end
go


select dbo.udf_SecondSentence('Tom is a cat. He loves playing outside. He also love eating.')
```